# Which Google cloud instance should I use to deploy a simple dynamic website

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently working on Google cloud platform. Periodically, I plan to execute a function which will insert and update positioning data on my Google cloud storage.

Then, I want to make these data available through a simple website with an URL. I see on Google cloud platform (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting) some way to make website (WordPress on Compute Engine, LAMP stack on Compute Engine, Cloud run, Compute engine, App engine and firebase hosting) but I didn't understand well which solution will be better for me.

Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The consider if you are asking an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Google App Engine (GAE) is a PaaS (Platform as a service)**.

In simple terms, it is like someone giving you a functioning computer where everything has been configured and all software has been installed (OS, memory, hard disk, etc) and the person is also responsible for maintaining it (adding more memory when it becomes slow, adding more hard drive when the storage becomes full, etc).

All you have to do is run your program on the machine.

2. **Google Compute Engine (GCE) is an IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service)**.

In simple terms, it is like someone dumping all the different hardware and software needed to assemble a computer on a table. You are then responsible for figuring out what you need (how much storage you need, how much memory you need, which OS you need, etc) and picking those from the table and assembling a computer to run your program.

After you have assembled the computer and your program is running, you also have to monitor it and determine if more hardware or memory is needed and then add those.

Based on what you have described, I would recommend going with GAE. Your use-case looks like a simple situation of a front end (website) to display data from storage. Also, the fact that you asked this question, gives me the impression that you're not extremely knowledgeable about Google Cloud products (i mean no disrespect) so you want to use something that is simple and straight-forward (i.e. a solution where Google handles all the heavy lifting).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's indeed more simple that I thought, I will investigate more the documentation of GCP following your advice.

Answer (score 1):

GCP has different products for different use cases which in most cases are designed for building more complex solutions which are scalable horizontally and vertically.
Based on the application you want to build you have to choose each building block taking into account it's properties and your requirements.

To cut the long story short if you want to host simple static page I suggest you:

1. Create a bucket on GCS
2. Add permission for allUsers to Storage Object Viewer
3. Edit websiste configuration for the bucket setting up index.html and 404.html

Of you go, your bucket is available publicly to everyone, cost you whatever space and traffic you will use above the free tier.

Here you will find detailed info about the steps you need to take from goodle:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Cloud Run, GKE, App Engine leave for the moment when you know that you need them for some reason.